# Extract substring from column

Tags: python, dataframe, substring

I'm trying to extract the hour from the entire data+time column df['Start Time']. Is there any easy way to do that using str.extract()? Any support is appreciated!!

```
    Start Time             
2019-01-14 07:42:00    
2019-01-14 05:29:00    
2019-01-14 08:01:00    
2019-01-18 04:20:00  
2019-01-14 05:30:00   
       ... 
2018-04-09 10:15:33   
2018-12-14 06:36:46     
2018-04-11 07:51:24
```

I've tried:

```
df['Start Hour'] = df['Start Time'].str.split(' ', 1)
```

Output

```
    Start Time             
2019-01-14   
2019-01-14  
2019-01-14    
2019-01-18  
2019-01-14  
       ... 
2018-04-09    
2018-12-14    
2018-04-11
```

Desired Output

```
    Start Time             
07
05 
08  
04
05
   ... 
10
06  
07
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You shoud share code snippet you have tried

Comment: I tried str.split and I only get the yyyy-mm-dd part but not the hh:mm:ss. I would like to only get hh out of the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your value to a pandas datetime object, and extract hour:

```py
df['Hour'] = df['Start Time'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).hour)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My column is in int64.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").dt.hour
```

[series.dt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html)